# Can somebody give explain of how this code able to reverse the string

Tags: c++, c, stack

The following code is able to reverse the inputted string even though I have used only a single character variable to read the input. Is the code using stack inherently? When compiled with gcc or online gdb, it is able to reverse the string. When implemented in C++, it is doing nothing. My understanding of the code is that it should not print anything. Since `printf` in definition of reverseSentence() will never be executed.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   void reverseSentence();
   int main()
   {
       Printf("Enter the sentence: ");
       reverseSentence();
       return 0;
    }
    void reverseSentence()
    { 
         char c;
         scanf("%c",&c);
          if(c!='\n')
        {
           reverseSentence();
           printf("%c",c); 
         }

        }
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: It works exactly the same as it would if you called a function that wasn't called "reverseSentence" – call the function, and print something when it has returned. The Big Secret of recursion is that there is nothing special about recursion.

Comment: The best way to understand small codes like this is to compile the code and run the program in the debugger. Step line by line through the code and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It reads in a character, calls itself, then prints out the character it read. Unless it reads in a newline, in which case it just terminates.

Let's try it for "AB\n".

1 We read in a character, "A".
1 We call ourself:
2 ... We read in a character, "B"
2 ... We call ourself:
3 ... ...We read in a newline
3 ... ...      We return
2 ...  We output the character we read, "B".
2 ...  We return
1 We output the character we read, A".

So for the input "AB", it prints "BA", thus reversing the input.

> Since printf in definition of reverseSentence() will never be executed.

I don't see how you get that. As soon as a newline is read in, the innermost call to `reverseSentence` returns, causing the calling function to resume.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Correct me if i am wrong. From the explanation you have given in steps kind 1 1 2 2.Your explanation is saying like copies of 'c' are made on every recursive call.My understand is whenever we call a function from inside the same function, there won't be any copy made (of the recursive function) for the new call. So the memory available for variable 'c' (in this problem) is fixed through out the code execution and has same address for the variable no matter how many times you call it. From that how can a single character variable can have memory of any length of string.

Comment: No copy of the *function* is made, but each instance of the function has its own instance of `c` at a different address. When you call the function, a new `c` is created that exists for the duration of that invocation of the function.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> Since printf is in defintion of reverseSentence it will never be
> executed.

That's incorrect, what you are missing is that `reverseSentence` calls itself from inside an `if` statement. If that `if` is false then `reverseSentence` does not call itself and so it returns and the following `printf` statement is executed.

Code looks fine to me, I'd only make one change

```
int main()
{
    printf("Enter the sentence: ");
    reverseSentence();
    printf("\n"); // <- change here
    return 0;
}
```

Now I except you'll see output in C and C++.